# Input field doesn't work inside vue-drag-resize

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Im using vue-drag-resize from https://github.com/kirillmurashov/vue-drag-resize.

I can't focus and type anything inside input text field if it is placed inside vue-drag resize component. Does anybody know solution how to fix this problem?

Comment: do you have an online link or else post some code to reproduce the issue??

Comment: you may use drag events as defined in the github repository and remove drag classesa and attributes from dragged element on dragStop event. This should fix it i suppose

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue when I'm using vue-drag-resize npm on my vue project.
In the vue-drag-resize container, input field didn't work.
So I fixed it with input **focus** function

This is Code Example

```
<template>
   <VueDragResize>
       <input v-model="name" ref="input" @click="inputClicked" />
   </VueDragResize>
</template>
<script>
...
...
methods: {
    inputClicked() {
        this.$refs.input.focus()
    }
}
</script>
```

Sometimes, we will have **"... .focus is not a function"** error.

If you faced this error, please try like this

```
this.$refs.input[0].focus()
this.$refs.input.$el.focus()
```

Either one will work.

Answer (score -3):

```
@activated="onActivated"

methods: {
    onActivated() {
        this.$refs['yourinput'].focus();
      }
```

Comment: Please add some more information as to how to fix the issue

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!